# Is Speculative Realism pluralist

Tags: metaphysics, continental-philosophy

While there are many speculative realists, the fundamental foundations of metaphysics related to anti-correlationist stance and post-continental philosophy remains pretty similar.

While some might argue that since many speculative realists are metaphysical realists, they are predominantly monists. However, object-oriented ontology and Graham Harman raises different perspective considering the "equality of the objects". Is it correct, and if yes, which category does Speculative Realists belong to: pluralists (dualists, nondualists or any other), monists, etc., and why?

Comment: Already your first sentence contains three philosophical buzzwords. It would be helpful to provide some explanation what you mean by these designations. - Possibly you tend to a certain answer concerning the question in your last sentence. It would be interesting to learn which thoughts you already have developed concerning this point.

Comment: I don't know that the assumption that pluralism is at odds with monism holds. I mean, I understand why someone would think that - monism means "one-ism" and plural is contrary to one - plural literally means more than one - but I think pluralism and monism are kind of *about different things*. Monism just states the universe is made of a unified type of thing, whereas pluralism is more the claim that there are multiple simultaneous emergent types of processes in the world. A monist could (and most monists probably do) believe in the second statement there.

Comment: When you say 'is it correct', are you asking if speculative realism is correct?

Comment: @edelex No. I am asking whether it is considered pluralist metaphysically.

Comment: Most philosophers are highly resistant to having their views “bucketed” into categories.  Hence bucketing philosophers at all is often problematic, and if done at all it is best done at the lowest level of large categories. You appear to have a highly refined set of bucketing categories that are presumed in your question, which appear to be unlikely to be widely accepted by the people you are bucketing, or by other conversants here. Could you recast your question to be more explicit about what the view is you are asking about, and the specific philosophers (if that matters), without bucketing?

Comment: @Dcleve I am not sure on how I should do that. Would you mind to provide some additional information on how to improve the question?

Comment: I am fairly well read in contemporary philosophy (tho more 20th than 21st century), but have no idea what speculative realism, anti-correlationist, or post continental are meant to describe, and have only the vaguest of inklings about object oriented ontology.  Answering your question would require me to do extensive research to even understand its terms.  And the person who can most usefully research this would be you.  HAVE you researched it?  If so, and you still have a question, I would suggest translating from jargon, say where you found partial info, then say what still needs clarifying.